# Game Theory (continuous utility, pure strategy)

Tags: optimization, game-theory

I have a game in which two players, 1 and 2, choose a non-negative real number level of effort $e_1,e_2$ respectively.  Their cost for this choice is $ce_i$ for $i=1,2$ where $c>0$ is the same for both.  Their joint reward is $e_1^{\alpha_1}e_2^{\alpha_2},\quad \alpha_i\in (0,1)$ and they split this evenly--their utility on each strategy profile is their share of the reward minus the cost.

So the payoff for player one seems to be $e_1^{\alpha_1}e_2^{\alpha_2}/2-ce_1$ and similarly for player 2.  Of course $(0,0)$ is a Nash equilibrium, and I need to find the others.

I assume (although I'm not perfectly sure about this) that I do this with partial derivatives.  I know that a necessary condition is for the respective partials to be $0$.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial e_1}(e_1^{\alpha_1}e_2^{\alpha_2}-ce_1) = 0 = \alpha_1e_1^{\alpha_1-1}e_2^{\alpha_2}-c$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial e_2}(e_1^{\alpha_1}e_2^{\alpha_2}-ce_2) = 0 = \alpha_2e_1^{\alpha_1}e_2^{\alpha_2-1}-c$$

These equations together imply

$$
    \alpha_1e_1^{\alpha_1-1}e_2^{\alpha_2}=c = \alpha_2e_1^{\alpha_1}e_2^{\alpha_2-1} \Rightarrow\\
    e_2=\alpha_2e_1/\alpha_1
$$

However, I'm not sure what a sufficient condition should be here.  I recall from Calculus that, if you are optimizing a two-variable function, you use a second-order condition, but in this case I'm not optimizing just one function but two of them.  My belief is that I use this solution to test the second-order condition on each function individually, but I want to check with someone smarter than me that this works as I think it does, and that I'm doing what I should be doing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I think this is fine, you might want to check that the second order derivative is negative, so you have a maximum, but otherwise I don't see any problems. Also the other variable should be thought of as fixed for the payoff function, since the player can only change his number

$$ f_1(e_1) = e_1^{\alpha_1}e_2^{\alpha_2} - ce_1$$

so this is not a two variable function.